I never left vs I have never left ( convey the meaning until now)
see the clip here
In the movie Mother of the Bride, A bellman talking with the customers:
(1) I came over here on holiday 32 years ago, and I never left
So, how about this sentence using present perfect:
(2) I came over here on holiday 32 years ago, and I have never left
Is that "I have never left= I never left" to talk about an action until now?

Americans may often prefer simple past ('I never left') in situations where British English speakers use present perfect ('I have never left') to speak about a past action that they consider relevant to the present. Is the bellman American?

@MichaelHarvey - By his speech, he's an Englishman settled in the US, so presumably he has picked up the American usage.

@KateBunting - or was directed to do so by the scriptwriters. It is fairly common for even UK domestically produced TV shows (and films) to have their dialogue 'Americanised' to some extent, to avoid frightening the horses, I guess. I heard a character in 'Silent Witness' address a British detective sergeant as 'Detective Smith', and not 'DS Smith' as any normal UK forensic pathologist would.

@MichaelHarvey - I meant the character, not the actor! (BTW I had to look up 'bellman'. I  (and presumably you) would call him a porter.)

@KateBunting - I meant the character, too. They used to be called 'bellboys' whatever their age. I think the actor is Keith Shillitoe who is British. On the IMDB site I think the role is listed as Maître D', not 'bellman'.

Having thought about it some more, I think ' I came over here on holiday 32 years ago, and I never left' is perfectly natural and normal whether the speaker is British or American.

Wow, @KateBunting, it had never occurred to me that bellman (and presumably its irony-based cousin bellhop) might not be used in the UK. Now that I think of it though, I can hear some Dame May Whitty character who desired assistance intoning profoundly non-rhotically, “Porter!”

There's a song called 'Bell Boy" in The Who's rock opera 'Quadrophenia'. It relates to the anguish of a character who finds out that a teen hero is now 'only' a bell boy at a hotel in Brighton (UK).

"I never left" in this context means he didn't leave permanently as expected when his holiday ended. He might have visited other places since then, but he always came back here.
"I've never left" could be more literal: He's been in this place continuously since he first visited and never gone anywhere else. Someone would use this construction to complain that they never get to travel. If he said this instead, I'd pick up the same basic meaning and wouldn't necessarily assume he meant it literally, but I'd be wondering.
The difference comes from the nature of the past simple and past continuous. The past simple emphasizes a single point in time when he would have gone home, but didn't.
